# CartoDB change tooltip CSS

Tags: carto

How can I change the css for the [CartoDB tooltip](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-5-0)?

I found this css below in the source but am having a hard time referencing it. Are there any examples of a customized, styled tooltip?

/* CartoDB tooltip control */

div.cartodb-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
  }

div.cartodb-tooltip p {
    font-family: "robotoregular", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #FFF, 1px -1px 0 #FFF, -1px 1px 0 #FFF, 1px 1px 0 #FFF;
  }

Answer (score 1):

Here is the css rule that I changed for the CSS

```
.cartodb-tooltip p {
   font-size: 25px !important;          
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartocss/properties/
CartoDB has their own format for changing css properties which is actually rather different. In the site search "text-size" to see their sizing property.